# Angular10 ng-class is differ from class tag why?

Tags: angular10

I have an issue with ng-class, when i add the condition to check if index is equal to 0 then some active class add to div.

**Expected Result:** ng-reflect-ng-class="tab-pane fade active" class="tab-pane fade active"

**Currently:** ng-reflect-ng-class="tab-pane fade active" class="tab-pane fade"

**Code Ref:** https://prnt.sc/1losfz5

Ref: https://prnt.sc/1lopmom

Note: Same code is working fine in another modules.
Ref: https://prnt.sc/1lorduf

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index;" [ngClass]="i==0?'tab-pane fade active':'tab-pane fade'">{{item}}</li>
```

we can add the class based on the condition...